# How to log a sql exception?

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch-finally

I am trying to log the stack trace in the below way it is working fine but i am trying to figure out is there any other efficient way to do for logging the exception?

```
 catch (SQLException e) {
                LOG.error(
                          "Sql Exception: "  
                                   + e.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + "." 
                                   + e.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), e);
                throw e;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
LOG.error("Sql Exception", e);
```

Notice the second parameter `e`. When the Exception/Throwable is passed in like this, loggers include the stack trace. No need to work with `e.getStackTrace()` manually (and awkwardly).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `+ e.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + "." + e.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()` in your code, this information is generated by the logger itself using the Exception stack trace.